Navbar Toggler Icon is invisible using Reactstrap
I am trying to incorporate the "hamburger" icon for the drop down menu in my React website. I though it came already attached to NavbarToggler with reactstrap/bootstrap install. The icon is clickable, and will drop down the menu, but the icon is not there.
Here is the code for my NavbarToggle component:
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  Navbar,
  NavbarBrand,
  Collapse,
  NavbarToggler,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
} from "reactstrap";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const NavbarToggle = () => {
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Navbar color="light" sticky="top" expland="md">
      <NavbarBrand className="ms-5" href="/"></NavbarBrand>
      <NavbarToggler onClick={() => setMenuOpen(!menuOpen)} />
      <Collapse isOpen={menuOpen} navbar>
        <Nav className="ms-auto" navbar>
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/">
              <i className="fa fa-home fa-lg" /> Home
            </NavLink>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/about">
              <i className="fa fa-info fa-lg" /> About
            </NavLink>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/contact">
              <i className="fa fa-address-card fa-lg" /> Contact
            </NavLink>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/projects">
              <i className="fa fa-list fa-lg" /> Projects
            </NavLink>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/works">
              <i className="fa fa-home fa-lg" /> Works
            </NavLink>
          </NavItem>
        </Nav>
      </Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default NavbarToggle;

I have tried to include the image in the SCSS for bootstrap, and a few other things, but the closest I got was having the icon just be a solid black box.
